# Diving Competition - Java Program

Tags: java, arrays, joptionpane

I am working on a diving competition program that is similar to another problem on the site. The goal of the program is to ask the user to input the diver's name, the seven judges scores, and the difficulty rating of the dive. Once that information is input, I create a Diver object based on my user created Diver class. Then using the insertDiver method, I am supposed to be adding divers to an array of divers in the order such that the highest finalScore is first. I am not supposed to be sorting the array. Using JOptionPane showMessageDialog output, display the rankings in order from highest finalScore to the lowest finalScore. Since, I am passing an array object to the insertDiver method, the array is dead after completion of the method. I tried making the Diver[] array a global variable but those results were not good either. So bottom line, I don't know how to add the divers to the Divers array by highest finalScore and I don't know how to display the results either. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DivingCompetition
{


public static void main(String[] args)
{
  String[] choices = {"Add Diver/Scores", "View Diver Standings", "Search for a diver", "Exit Program"};
  String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What do you want to do?", "Diving Competition", 
                 JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, choices, choices[0]);
  while(!input.equals("Exit Program"))
  {
     if (input.equals("Add Diver/Scores"))
        addDiver();
     else if (input.equals("View Diver Standings"))
        viewStandings();
     else if (input.equals("Search for a diver"))
        searchDiver();
     else
        System.exit(0);
     input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What do you want to do?", "Diving Competition", 
                 JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, choices, choices[0]);      
  }
}
public static void addDiver()
{
  String scoreInvalid = "The score must be between 0 and 10";
  String difficultyInvalid = "The difficulty must be between 1.2 and 3.8";
  double[] scores = new double[7];
  int i = 0;
  String tempScore = "";
  String tempDifficulty = "";
  double realDifficulty = 0;
  double realScore = 0;
  int numScores = 0;

  String diverName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the diver's name:");
  while (numScores < 7)
  {
     tempScore = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the seven judge's scores one at a time");
     realScore = Double.parseDouble(tempScore);
     while (realScore < 0 || realScore > 10)
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scoreInvalid, "Invalid Score", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        tempScore = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the corrected score");
        realScore = Double.parseDouble(tempScore);
     }

     scores[i] = realScore;
     i++;
     numScores++;
  }
  tempDifficulty = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the difficulty rating of the dive");
  realDifficulty = Double.parseDouble(tempDifficulty);

  while (realDifficulty < 1.2 || realDifficulty > 3.8)
  {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, difficultyInvalid, "Invalid Difficulty", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
     tempDifficulty =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the                 corrected difficulty rating of the dive");
     realDifficulty = Double.parseDouble(tempDifficulty);
  }
  Diver aDiver = new Diver(diverName, scores, realDifficulty);
  Diver[] dArray = new Diver[30];
  insertDiver(aDiver, dArray);             
}
public static insertDiver(Diver newElement, Diver[] diverArray)
{
  int addpos = 0;
  int currentSize = 0;

  if (diverArray[addpos] == null)
  {
     diverArray[addpos] = newElement;
     currentSize++;
     addpos++;
  }   
  else
     while (addpos < diverArray.length)
     {
        if (newElement.getFinalScore() > diverArray[addpos].getFinalScore())
        {
           diverArray[addpos] = newElement;
           currentSize++;
           break;
        }   
        else
           addpos++;
     }      
  if (addpos >= diverArray.length)
     diverArray[addpos] = newElement;
  else
  {
     currentSize++;
     for (int i = currentSize - 1; i > addpos; i--)
     {
        diverArray[i] = diverArray[i-1];
        diverArray[addpos] = newElement;
     }           

  }
for (int i = 0; i<diverArray.length; i++)
  {
     System.out.println(diverArray[i]);//just to see the contents of the array printed
  }

}
public static void viewStandings()
{

}
public static void searchDiver()
{

}    
}
```

Here is the Diver class that I created:

```
public class Diver
{//begin class

private final double MULTIPLIER = 0.6;
private String diverName;
private double[] scores = new double[7];
private double difficulty, finalScore;
//---------------------------------------------------   
public Diver(String dN, double[] s, double d)
{
  setDiver(dN, s, d);
}
//---------------------------------------------------   
public String getName()
{
  return diverName;
}
//---------------------------------------------------   
public double getDifficulty()
{
  return difficulty;
}
//---------------------------------------------------
public double[] getScores()
{
  return scores;
}
//---------------------------------------------------   
public double getFinalScore()
{
  return finalScore;
}
//---------------------------------------------------   
public String toString()
{
  return "Diver Name: " + diverName + " Judge's Scores: " + scores +
         " Dive Difficulty: " + difficulty;
}
//---------------------------------------------------   
public void setDiverName(String name)
{
  diverName = name.toUpperCase();
}
//---------------------------------------------------   
public void setDifficulty(double diff)
{
   difficulty = diff;
}
//---------------------------------------------------   
public void setScores(double[] sc)
{
   for(int i=0; i < 7; i++)
     scores[i] = sc[i];
}
//---------------------------------------------------   
public void setDiver(String nme, double[] score, double dif)
{
  setDiverName(nme);
  setScores(score);
  setDifficulty(dif);
  computeFinalScore();  
}
//---------------------------------------------------
private void computeFinalScore()
{
  double smallest = scores[0];
  double largest = scores[0];
  double scoreSum = 0;

  for(int i=1; i< scores.length; i++)
  {
     if(scores[i] > largest)
        largest = scores[i];
     else if (scores[i] < smallest)
        smallest = scores[i];                 
  }

  for( double i : scores)
  {
     scoreSum += i;
  }

  finalScore =  (scoreSum - smallest - largest) * difficulty * MULTIPLIER;         
} 
//---------------------------------------------------   
}//end class
```

Comment: You should probably use a list of some sort for the divers; much, much easier.

Comment: Have a loot at what Dave suggested:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/collection.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Write a Comparator for Diver Class and then you can use a collection like TreeSet which will make your life little easy.
2. For Display you Can use JTable.

Here is sample running code for you :

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class DivingCompetition
{
    static DiverComparator comp = new DiverComparator();
    static Set<Diver> divers = new TreeSet<Diver>(comp); 

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] choices = {"Add Diver/Scores", "View Diver Standings", "Search for a diver", "Exit Program"};
        String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What do you want to do?", "Diving Competition", 
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, choices, choices[0]);
        while(!input.equals("Exit Program"))
        {
            if (input.equals("Add Diver/Scores"))
                addDiver();
            else if (input.equals("View Diver Standings"))
                viewStandings();
            else if (input.equals("Search for a diver"))
                searchDiver();
            else
                System.exit(0);
            input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What do you want to do?", "Diving Competition", 
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, choices, choices[0]);      
        }
    }
    public static void addDiver()
    {
        String scoreInvalid = "The score must be between 0 and 10";
        String difficultyInvalid = "The difficulty must be between 1.2 and 3.8";
        double[] scores = new double[7];
        int i = 0;
        String tempScore = "";
        String tempDifficulty = "";
        double realDifficulty = 0;
        double realScore = 0;
        int numScores = 0;

        String diverName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the diver's name:");
        while (numScores < 7)
        {
            tempScore = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the seven judge's scores one at a time");
            realScore = Double.parseDouble(tempScore);
            while (realScore < 0 || realScore > 10)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scoreInvalid, "Invalid Score", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                tempScore = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the corrected score");
                realScore = Double.parseDouble(tempScore);
            }

            scores[i] = realScore;
            i++;
            numScores++;
        }
        tempDifficulty = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the difficulty rating of the dive");
        realDifficulty = Double.parseDouble(tempDifficulty);

        while (realDifficulty < 1.2 || realDifficulty > 3.8)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, difficultyInvalid, "Invalid Difficulty", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            tempDifficulty =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the                 corrected difficulty rating of the dive");
            realDifficulty = Double.parseDouble(tempDifficulty);
        }
        Diver aDiver = new Diver(diverName, scores, realDifficulty);

        divers.add(aDiver);
    }
    public static void viewStandings()
    {
        Object[][] rows = new Object[divers.size()][]; 
        int i = 0;
        for(Diver d : divers) {
            rows[i] = new Object[3];
            rows[i][0] = i+1;
            rows[i][1] = d.getName();
            rows[i][2] = d.getFinalScore();
            i++;
        }
            Object[] cols = {
                "Rank","Name","Final Score"
            };
            JTable table = new JTable(rows, cols);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));

    }
    public static void searchDiver()
    {

    }    
}
class DiverComparator implements Comparator<Diver> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Diver o1, Diver o2) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (int) (o2.getFinalScore() - o1.getFinalScore());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The program exits and no data in memory is available anymore. To keep the program running you have to use a JFrame or in generell a Thread which keeps the application alive.

Answer (score 0):

Move this line of code to the top of your class:

```
public class DivingCompetition{
    static Diver[] dArray = new Diver[30];

    public static void main(String[] args){
    etc
```

Although it is not the best solution it is the easier one for you to implement. The problem that you had is that the array is dead, as you said, after the completion of the method, because local variables are supposed to die after their parent code is finished. If you declare your array like this, you can access it from everywhere in your class.

To add more Divers, just search for in the dArray for a place with null.

Lastly for your code to work you need to change your insertDiver method to:

```
public static void insertDiver(Diver newElement, Diver[] diverArray)
```

In order to put divers afterwards, without sorting the array in the end, you have to implement a simple sorting algorithm WHILE you are adding divers:

1)Put the first diver on the first position.

2)Compare the second's diver score and if grater than the firsts, move your first driver one position towards the end of the array, and put the second driver on the first place. If not, put the second diver in the second position.

3)Subsequently, for every new diver, what you will do is to check if their score is higher that someone's else in the array and if it is move that one and all previous divers with less high score one position towards the end, so they can make space for the new diver with high score greater than theirs.

f.e. we want to sort [12,45,34,78] with that order:

```
12 -> [null,null,null,null]

45 -> [12,null,null,null]

34 -> [45,12,null,null]

78 -> [45,34,12,null]

      [78,45,34,12]
```

Comment: I can not just add Divers to a position that is null. The divers have to be entered into the array so that the diver with the highest finalScore is in the 0th position. I am not allowed to sort the array after entering the divers.

Comment: OK excellent I think I have finished that method based on your suggestions! Thank you so much! Now that the array has everything in the proper order I just need to display the "rankings" in a JOptionPane showMessageDialog. Would you be able to expand on that further? I understand a loop is probably needed but just a hint at how to set that up?

Comment: I did not quite understand your question. Do you need to create a string with all the high scores?

Comment: I need to build or concatenate a String that displays the contents of the array. The output should show the ranking (if in 0th position of array, ranking needs to display 1st place), the diver's name, and the diver's final score formatted into 3 vertical columns.

Comment: hint: String asd = a + b + c; Where a, b and c can be anything. So what you have to do is just find the data you want like diver.getHighScore() and add them to a string. Is that ok?

Comment: @AbhorrentScorn . U can refer my answer for UI also apart from sorting logic.